# change cursor by an image not working in browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

I want to change my cursor into the same image when i click on it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#ggimg").click(function() {
        $("#ggimg").hide();
        $('#cursor').css('cursor','28283198.jpg"),-moz-zoom-in');
        //$('#cursor').css('cursor','28283198.jpg"),default');
    });
});
```

```css
#cursor {
     width: 200px; 
     height: 200px; 
     border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor" style="border:solid 1px;"></div>
<img src="../img/basket_anm.png" id='ggimg'>
```

please share some idea. thanks

Comment: you mean something like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/ap2g2/

Comment: well this give me some idea to do it..and i am trying, actually i want to catch some fruits with the basket. fruits are dropping but i want my cursor to become basket so that i can catch fruits. that is why i want to change my cursor. but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide cursor url as following way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#ggimg").click(function() {
        $("#ggimg").hide();
        $('#cursor').css('cursor','url(28283198.jpg),auto');
    });
});
```

Comment: friends. its all about extension (Niet the Dark Absol) was correct. with .cur its working...thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

`.jpg` is not technically a valid cursor file. Cross-browser valid cursors are `.cur` and `.ani`

However it is usually a better idea to have an image element on the page following the mouse - much easier and more user-friendly. After all, what if your user doesn't have a mouse (ie touchscreen)?

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajey/76Uqp/

make use of `cursor` property and mention the image path in the `url`

its better not to use .jpg format for cross browser issues.